# Не подключается layout в java класе ( AndroidStudio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Создаю в папке res leyout с именем main_leyout.xml !
Потом в java класе делаю  Override метода onCreate. Выглядит это так:

```
package com.example.vitaliy.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainLayoutActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    }
}
```

Но андроид студио видет ошибку...от так все выгладит в окне IDEA:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно сделать чтобы исправить ошибку ????

Разметка Activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainLayoutActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Добавить оператор импорта для R, или написать так com.example.vitaliy.R.layout.main_layout

Comment: @nekaneka, как это можно сделать (импорт)???

Comment: либо import com.example.vitaliy.R; либо com.example.vitaliy.R.layout.main_layout где setContentView

Comment: @nekaneka, не помогли...оба варианта !!! :( Что- то  делаю не так ...

Comment: @Vitaliy Жмакните два раза на красный onCreate. Покажите, что в этом случае пишет.

Comment: @Владимир, сделал так import android.R; і мой R теперь без ошибки...НО  maim_layout (красным подсвечивает)!!!

Comment: @nekaneka, проблему с R помогло исправить import android.R; но сразу появилась проблема с main_layout

Comment: попробуйте сбилдить заново проект. Если не поможет, возможно какая-то ошибка в lain_layout.xml

Comment: Так очевидно вы не тот R импортируете, нужно импортировать R именно вашего проекта.

Comment: @Vitaliy Поставьте курсор на ```R```, в ```AndroidStudio``` нажмите сочетание клавиш Alt + Enter и там выберите импорт с именем пакета вашего приложения.

Comment: @temq, что при создании проекта видает ошибки:
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'. ------------------ Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'

Что с этим делать ????

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Импортирование не поможет, так как это главный пакет и R-класс уже находится в нем. Скорее всего проблема в IDE, попробуй пересоздать проект.

Comment: вы абсолютно неправы.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо импортировать класс R, сгенерированный вашим приложением. В вашем случае это будет выглядеть так:

```
import com.example.vitaliy.helloworld.R
```

Comment: та пробовал я ..... не помогает !!! 
Раньше такого не было.....Но сейчас при создании проекта выкидывает такие ошибки:
------------------------
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
------------------
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе разметку активити.

Comment: @ЮрийСПбб привел...
После того как у меня не вышло сделать активити вручную, я сделал это автоматически при создании проекта....результат тот же...

Comment: Ну... Могу только посоветовать обновить всё что можно в SDK manager и/или переустановить Android Studio, т.к. если у вас простейшие проекты не собираются, то дело, видать, в IDE.